# Get value of cell on the left of current one

Tags: google-sheets

Which is the correct formula to get the value of cell on the left of current one. I've tried `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1)` but it populates the error of `circular dependency`.

Answer (score 36):

I tried this and it's working (in excel at least):

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$","")),0,-1)
```

The issue I believe is that `ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())` returns something like $A$2 which locks the cell, so you need to remove the `$` in the before using the offset.

EDIT: Overlooked something really simple xD (this one works both in excel and in g-spreadsheet

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try if this works :) p/s: this still doesn't work I have " error: Circular dependency detected "

Comment: @Vdt Hmm, I just tried a simple `=offset(indirect("C8"),0,1)` in g-spreadsheets and it still throws the error, whereas `=offset(C8,0,1)` doesn't. So, I played around a bit more and came up with a neater solution. See the edit in my answer!

Comment: Your second sample of code works great for me in Google Sheets, thanks!

Comment: @ShaneReustle Awesome :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))` as already mentioned, but you can also use the simpler

```
INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)
```